# Neumann theorem for Bessel function of the first kind (arbitrary order)

Tags: summation, bessel-functions

There is a [Neumann theorem](https://www.math.ust.hk/~machiang/150/Intro_bessel_bk_Nov08.pdf), proving that:

$J_0 \big(\sqrt{Z^2+z^2 - 2Zz \cos \phi} \big)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \epsilon_k J_k(Z) J_k (z) \cos k \phi$

where $\epsilon_0=1$, and $\epsilon_k = 2$: $k\geq 1$. It is assumed that $\sqrt{Z^2+z^2 - 2Zz \cos \phi} = |\vec{Z} - \vec{z}|$.

Does anyone know of a generalization for Bessel functions of arbitrary order $J_m \big(\sqrt{Z^2+z^2 - 2Zz \cos \phi} \big)$: $m$ is any integer?

Comment: The $x$ should be a $z$.

Comment: In case one would need it, the generalization can be found here: https://quod.lib.umich.edu/u/umhistmath/ACV1415.0001.001/140?rgn=full+text;view=pdf

Comment: There some more generalizations in Chap. 11, pp 358